# DriveApp.searchFiles doesn't work for particular search

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm experiencing an issue with the `DriveApp.searchFiles()` in Apps Script.

If I search files in Drive, whose names are like this (book names):

`Rif_Lettura_Nussbaum_02012014`

or

`La Torre_Lalatta_Legalizzare_Corriere_23122013`

the search find nothing in Drive.

```
function test(){


  var title='Rif_Lettura_Nussbaum_02012014';
  //Uncomment to try the working sample
  //var title='Rif_Lettura_Nussbaum_02012';



  var candidateFiles=DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "'+title+'"');
  var count=0;
  var fileCandidato;
  while (candidateFiles.hasNext()){
    count++;
    fileCandidato=candidateFiles.next();
    if(fileCandidato.getName().indexOf(title)!=-1){
      Logger.log("Finded: "+fileCandidato.getName());
    }

  }

  Logger.log(""+count+" files found with title "+title);

}
```

Substantially seems that the `searchFiles()` function works if the words separated by space have length less or equal then 26 (that is the number of letters of the English alphabet).

Anyone have found this error, and know a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and let me tell you that it has nothing to do with how long is the file or folder name. **It's all about this `-` or `+`**.

Example: It works perfectly if I search this : `HELLO-STACKOVERFLOW-WHATS-UP-HOW-YOU-DOING-GOOD-BYE`

```
function searchDrive() {

  var myFolder = "HELLO-STACKOVERFLOW-WHATS-UP-HOW-YOU-DOING-GOOD-BYE"

  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders(
     'title contains "'+ myFolder +'"');
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
     var folder = folders.next();
     Logger.log(folder.getName());
 }
}
```

However, If i search this: `HELLO - STACKOVERFLOW` nothing happens, same thing with `HELLO + STACKOVERFLOW`.

In conclusion: `DriveApp` search function is incapable to handle `+`, `-` in file or folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Curious case, if you use the following work:

```js
...
//var title = 'Rif_Lettura_Nussbaum_02012014';
var title = 'Rif_Lettura_Nussbaum_02012'; // title.length <= 26
...
var candidateFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + title + '"');
...
```

However, the following would also work:

```js
...
var title = 'Rif_Lettura_Nussbaum_02012014';
...
var candidateFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles('title = "' + title + '"');
...
```

In the documentation does not mention anything about this, or if there is a limit of 26 characters.

I see you opened an Issue ([Issue 3549: DriveApp.searchFiles doesn't work for long words](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3549)), will place a link there to this question.